# how to read the shape of the numpy array after numpy stack

Tags: numpy, stack

I am doing stack operation on two 2D array using numpy.

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(4, 4))
b = np.random.randint(6, 10, size=(4, 4))

f = np.stack((a, b), axis=2)
```

I checked the shape of the f array.

```
f.shape
(4, 4, 2)
```

in the obtained shape `(4, 4, 2)`, I would like to know what is first `4` represnts, second `4` represents and third element `2` reprents?

Comment: they don't 'represent' anything.  Just print thr three arrays, and see how values  match. `f[:,:,0]` should look luke `a`

Comment: I want my result after np.stack as one matrix is behind another matrix. Expected output siye should be 4 X 4 X 2. I do not think my approach gives desired result

Comment: That's what you got, a  (4,4,2) shape array..  'behind' is a vague descriptor.  Maybe you want (2,4,4).  numpy displays a (4,4,2) as 4 blocks of (4,2).